Node.js Puppeter | I can't pass Discord verification with 2captcha
Normally, I can pass the captcha when I try it on other sites. But there is no continue button on Discord, and that's why Discord does not see that this has been resolved.
As you can see below, I insert the captcha answer, but the captcha is not solved.

My code where I'm having problems:
import { Solver } from '2captcha-ts';

const solver = new Solver(apiKey);
const apiKey = 'apikey';

await page.waitForSelector("iframe[src*='https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/captcha/']");

    const sitekey = "4c672d35-0701-42b2-88c3-78380b0db560"

    console.log(`Sitekey: ${sitekey}`);

    const res = await solver.hcaptcha({
        pageurl: "https://discord.com/login",
        sitekey: sitekey,
    });

    console.log(res);

    const captchaAnswer = res.data;

    await page.evaluate((captchaAnswer) => {
        document.querySelector("textarea[name='h-captcha-response']").style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector("textarea[name='h-captcha-response']").value = captchaAnswer;
    }, captchaAnswer);

